# combo box drop down is not working even after I changed the height in designer

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, mfc, combobox

I am trying to give a fix for a combo box drop down list, since its not listing down properly .Only one item is being shown in the list rest all you can see by using arrow keys. I increased the height in designer too, anyways that is not the issue, why because its listing down in some machines and the same version is not working on my machine. I used the DDX_Control to assign this control to a variable.
Do we need to consider any other things which can impact the drop down list??

environment : vs2008, windows 7

May be I didn’t explain the problem in the right manner. After some google  search, I came to know that  I should mention some more points here.
I embed this combobox in a dialog editor, there are already some comboboxes those are working fine.
They might be created with the earlier versions of VS. Even I tried to  set the SetMinVisibleItems on this new combo, but always returns a failure.

Answer (score 2):

The height of a *dropped down* combobox is indeed the height of the control in the dialog template. If you make your combobox tall enough in the designer, then it should show several lines when opened.

According to what you did, the correct behaviour is the other computers. The wrong behaviour is your computer.

No, there are no other things to consider when designing a combobox. Ues your debugger and try to find out why the height of your combobox was reduced on your computer.

Comment: Well, I tried to find out the dropped down control rectangle , it is giving values, but the list is not dropping down. I am on windows SDK platform

Answer (score 1):

That can happen if the `No Integral Height` combobox property is set to true, and the height of the listbox component of the combobox has been inadvertently set to that of the combobox component.

The dialog designer allows you to set both of these two heights. Click on the dropdown arrow icon and then the bottom node then adjusts the listbox component. Change that height to be what you want, and set `No Integral Height` to be false.

This doesn't explain why it works on other machines, but give it a try.